# Reducing loading time of application built with Extjs

Tags: extjs

I have an Extjs-based application.while loading the page it's taking long time to load. According to the requirement, loading time should be reduced.

Here is my index.html file -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ext-theme-neptune-all-debug.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ext-all.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ext-theme-neptune.js"></script>
```

and all other js and css files are included accordingly.I have noticed that for the given three files above, loading time gets affected.

and here is the structure of my app -

- js
- css
- images
- index.html

Comment: Should you be using the `css/ext-theme-neptune-all-debug.css` file for production? My guess is that it is a much larger version of the css file that is made more readable for use while debugging.

Comment: Make sure you sure the sencha cmd to build your application for deployment it will make a condensed set of files for deployment which is must faster.

Comment: thanks outis for reply.I have used ext-theme-neptune-all-debug.css only to get neptune theme,nothing else more than that. and what about ext-all.js??

Comment: Isn't there a non-debug version for the neptune theme?

Comment: tnks N4TKD for reply.Yes, i have noticed that sencha cmd before, but could not be able to understand it's usage.

Comment: I second sencha command. The [tutorial](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/command_app) on the sencha docs is a good place to start.  The only thing i had issues with was installing ruby is required to run the build command to minify.

Comment: At last, i have created app in extjs.By default tabpanel appears.I have to add more tabs.In fact, I want to manage different js file(each containing different form) for different tab.After creating i just got stuck.plz help....

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to use Sencha Cmd. It's easy and it produces smallest possible files that are minimized; both javascript and css.